# Is there a way I can make a for loop, loop through different values to search for in an sqlite3 query

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a function that gets all of the data for a director each year but I have to create a new function for every year to change the `year_granted` to the next or previous year.  Is there a way I can make a loop that just uses one function and changes the `year_granted` to the next year.

```
def getDirectorsInfo2019(self):
   c.execute('SELECT first_name, last_name, year_granted, app_units_granted, 
   full_value_units_granted 
   FROM Directors INNER JOIN DirectorsUnits ON DirectorsUnits.id_number_unit = 
   Directors.id_number_dir 
   WHERE id_number_dir BETWEEN 1 AND 50 AND year_granted=2019')
   datas = c.fetchall()
   for people in data:
       people = [datas[0]]
   for people2 in [datas[0]]:
       peopl02 = list(pepl2)
   self.firstNAme = people2[0]
   self.year2019 = people2[2]
   self.lastNAme = people2[1]   
   self.aUnits2019 = people2[3]
   self.fUnits2019 = people2[4]
```

Comment: Can you change the function to take year_granted as a parameter and then use the parameter in the parameter string for `c.execute`?  Then you can call the function with the desired year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is fairly straightforward. The basic idea is to loop through a range and fill in the sql query using the DB-API’s "parameter substitution" method. It looks like this:

```
query = """
SELECT first_name, last_name, year_granted, app_units_granted, full_value_units_granted FROM Directors 
INNER JOIN DirectorsUnits ON DirectorsUnits.id_number_unit = Directors.id_number_dir 
WHERE id_number_dir BETWEEN 1 AND 50 AND year_granted=?
"""
# I used a triple-quote string here so that the line breaks are ignored
# Note that this loop would fetch data for 1998, 1999, 2000, and 2001, but not 2002
for year in range(1998, 2002):
    # Parameter substitution takes a list or tuple of values, so the value must be in a list even though there's only one
    rows = c.execute(query, [str(year),]).fetchall()
    for row in rows:
       #strictly speaking, you don't need these variable assignments, but it helps to show what's going on
       first_name = row[0]
       last_name = row[1]
       year = row[3]
       a_units = row[4]
       f_units = row[5]
       # do stuff with row data here, append to a list, etc.
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this does help a lot, but I am now getting this error; sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied. Which doesn't make sense because I am not even giving 4

Comment: Sorry, this is a common mistake, and my fault. Edited my post and added a comment explaining.

Comment: It is working now. Thank You very much for your help.

Comment: I actually have one more problem now, which is that it is only showing the last year in the range. Do you know how to access the other years?

Comment: You have to store them somewhere, as with all loops. For example, append them to a list that is defined outside the loop.

Comment: That's my problem, I was trying to do it inside the loop. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, this just removed over 2000 lines of almost exactly the same thing from my program so, Thank You.